# Using find and grep to Mimic findstr Command

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, grep, find

I recently switched from a Windows development environment to an Apple development environment. The move has been a challenging process, but I'm struggling with picking up UNIX based commands in terminal to makeup for the commands I used on a daily basis in Windows command prompt. Any help would greatly appreciated, explanations on a basic level of what's going on in the commands provided is a huge bonus for me as I'm trying to get a grasp on the UNIX commands, but reading the `man`ual is like reading a foreign language to me most of the time.

Here's my question: Is there a single line command, preferably short enough to memorize, that I can execute to mimic or produce very similar output to the following Windows CMD command:

```
findstr /s /c:"this piece of text" *.code
```

I use this command on Windows often to produce a result set that shows me where the text between the quotes resides in any of the files matching the *.code pattern in any subdirectories. This can be used to check version numbers of numerous files pulled back from servers to looking for where a variable was declared in a large project. The output comes in this form:

```
file1.code: other text this piece of text other text
file2.code: other text this piece of text other text
file3.code: other text this piece of text other text
file4.code: other text this piece of text other text
file5.code: other text this piece of text other text
```

Where other text is any other text found on the same line as my search string in the given file. I have searched through the questions here and found several people using `find . -name *.code` to build a list of files in the subdirectories. They then use the `-exec` flag from the `find` command paired with a `grep` sequence to search text. I tried this in several of the mentioned ways and was failing, I think due to escape sequences or missed characters. It would be awesome if there was a way to just give the command a string in between quotes that it just searched for as is.

I tried the following and wasn't getting any results... Maybe a syntax error?

```
find . -exec grep -H .getItemToChange().getItemAttributes()
```

**UPDATE**
The correct code is provided below with a great explanation by John. If this helps you like it helped me give his answer an upvote!

I was hoping to find the .java file with this function call in it in a large project. It wasn't giving me any results and it also didn't have a way to filter to only *.java.

Can anyone help me out here? Explanations to your commands are GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.code' -exec grep -H 'pattern' {} +
```

Make sure to quote `'*.code'` so the shell doesn't expand the `*` wildcard. Usually we do want the shell to do the expansion, but in this case we want the literal string `*.code` to be passed to `find` so it can do the wildcard expansion itself.

When you use `-exec` you need to put `{}` somewhere; it's the placeholder for the file names that are found. You also need either `\;` or `+` at the end of the command. It's how you signal to `find` where the end of `-exec`'s arguments are (it's possible to have other actions following `-exec`). `\;` will cause `grep` to be run once for each file while `+` runs a single `grep` on all of the files.

```
find . -name '*.code' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H 'pattern'
```

Another common way to do this is by chaining together `find` and `xargs`. I like using `-exec` better, but `find`+`xargs` works just as well. The idea here is that `xargs` takes file names passed in on stdin and runs the named command with those file names appended. To get a suitable list of file names passed in we pipe the output of a `find` command into `xargs`.

The `-print0` option tells `find` to print each file it finds along with a NUL character (`\0`). This goes hand in hand with `xargs`'s `-0` option. Using `-print0` and `-0` ensures that we can handle file names with unusual characters like whitespace and quotes correctly.

Comment: I just ran a couple of tests with your first code snippet and that works perfectly. I'll play around with the xargs version a little bit, but I think knowing what `{}` and `+` were actually doing was my missing piece. I didn't realize they were flags for the filename and the end of the exec command. The first code snippet seems easier to memorize. Many thanks!