# Check if adb device connected condition

Tags: android, batch-file, cmd, adb

How can I check adb device is connected in batch files?
I wrote "adb devices" in the batch file, but I want it as a condition so the app working smoothly and automatically
So if the user is not connected his device print no device and exit the app,
Otherwise resume the app.

Comment: Do you want a bash script that tell you if at lease one device is connected or not and do you mean TCP and USB connection type or only USB connection type ?

Comment: Only for USB connection

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pipe the output to `find` and analyse the errorlevel:

```
adb devices -l | find "device product:" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo No connected devices
) else (
    echo Found!
    ..............
)
```

Comment: Thanks,it's worked.
but i don't want to specify the device id
i want that any device if not connected to print something, and if connected resume the app without specify any id..
is it possible?

Comment: Thanks Man it's Worked Finally :D

Comment: can i handle the `adb install package.apk` result?
so if the result **!=Success** pause
otherwise close the window.

Comment: ok i've tried it but it's always returning **0** on error level(on both cases)
any ideas please?

Comment: Try googling for similar questions or ask a new question.

Comment: @ALLOMIRaj, in this code wOxxOm was checking `errorlevel` of the `find` command and not `adb` - so your statement in your new question about `adb` being able to set `errorlevel` to values other than `0` is false.

Comment: That's the solution, but today I found a problem with rooted phones, that not display more info then don't recognized as connected. I replaces `adb devices -l | find "device product:"` for @benjamin-k answer `adb devices | findstr "\<device\>"` and now works with rooted and not rooted devices.

Answer (score 10):

For user in bash or similar shell environment, try

```
$ adb get-state 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && echo 'device attached' || echo 'no device attached'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the easiest and is most accurate since it'll only find "device" and not other words containing the string such as "devices":

```
adb devices | findstr "\<device\>"
```

Take note that findstr works on Windows but not in Unix terminals. So the equivilent would be to use find and grep together. John explains this well in this page [Using find and grep to Mimic findstr Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414876/using-find-and-grep-to-mimic-findstr-command)